# Allocating and freeing memory in a loop in C

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I know there are a lot of answers about this topic here on StackOverflow, and they've been very helpful but I'm not sure about one thing. Let's say I have funcA and funcB:

```
char * funcA()
{
    char * arr = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);

    //store data in arr...

    return arr;
}

void funcB()
{
    char * arr;
    while(up to some finite value)
    {
        arr = funcA();
        //do stuff with array

        /* Do I perform these two lines here every iteration?*/
        free(arr)
        arr = NULL;
    }

    /*Or do I perform it only once, at the end of the loop?*/
    free(arr)
    arr = NULL;
}
```

I'm thinking `arr` is supposed to be freed in each iteration. Or will each iteration just "overwrite" the data in `arr`, and thus making it safe to only call free at the end of the loop? What is the correct way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: you have a memory leak. every time you call `funcA()`, you delete any "memory" of the previous allocations, leaving that chunk of ram allocated-but-lost. You have to free() the block when you're done with it, or at least keep track of the pointer malloc() gave you.

Comment: Simple rule: one `free` per `malloc`.

Comment: Each time you call `malloc` some memory is allocated. Each time you call `free` some memory is deallocated. Do you want to deallocate every block of memory you allocate, or only the last one?

Comment: @immibis Ok, so then for each iteration, I call free is what you're saying?

Comment: for every `malloc` there must be a `free`, otherwise you have a *memory leak*

Comment: @Ghost_Stark No, I'm saying what you need to figure it out yourself. It seems like you have - yes, you should call free inside the loop. Good job.

Comment: Do you have  reason to  call `malloc` in the loop?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call free(arr) in the loop, otherwise you'll loose the pointer to arr and leak memory for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Ok thanks, that's what I thought but I just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call free for every malloc/calloc.

```
char * funcA()
{
    char *arr = calloc(20, sizeof *arr); //allocation and initialize to 0
    if (arr) { //if successfully allocated
        //store data in arr...
    }
    return arr;
}

void funcB()
{
    char *arr;
    while (up to some finite value)
    {
        if ((arr = funcA())){ //if successfully allocated
            //do stuff with array

            free(arr);
            arr = NULL;
        } else {
            //allocation failed
            //deal with alloc error
        }
    }
}
```

You should also check for malloc errors, or you could get a segmentation fault

Comment: `if ((arr = funcA()) != NULL) {` would be better style.

Answer (score 2):

> /* Do I perform these two lines here every iteration?*/

Yes, just make sure you don't assign new memory address to `arr` after call to

```
arr = funcA();
```

and before call to `free`, otherwise you will have memory leak, because you will lose track of the memory returned by `funcA()` and won't be able to free it anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Every time where you do a `malloc` a `free` must take place too.

Take a look at the following program:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char *funcA(void){
    char *arr = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);

    strcpy(arr, "Michi");
    return arr;
}

void funcB(void){
    char *arr;
    int a = 0;

    while(a < 5){
        arr = funcA();
        printf("%s\n",arr);

        free(arr);
        arr = NULL;
        a++;
    }
}

int main(void){
    funcB();
    return 0;
}
```

This will output `Michi` 5 times:

> ```
> Michi
> Michi
> Michi
> Michi
> Michi
> ```

As you can see there are 5 `malloc` and 5 `free`, but what happen if we `free` outside of that while block?:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char *funcA(void){
    char *arr = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);

    strcpy(arr, "Michi");
    return arr;
}

void funcB(void){
    char *arr;
    int a = 0;

    while(a < 5){
        arr = funcA();
        printf("%s\n",arr);
        a++;
    }

    free(arr);
    arr = NULL;
}

int main(void){
    funcB();
    return 0;
}
```

Your program could run fine with no errors, but there is a problem, you just `malloc`ed 5 times and used `free` just one time.

You have memory leaks:

> ```
> ==3146== Command: ./program
> ==3146== 
> Michi
> Michi
> Michi
> Michi
> Michi
> ==3146== 
> ==3146== HEAP SUMMARY:
> ==3146==     in use at exit: 80 bytes in 4 blocks
> ==3146==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 1 frees, 100 bytes allocated
> ==3146== 
> ==3146== 80 bytes in 4 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
> ==3146==    at 0x4C2BBA0: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
> ==3146==    by 0x400597: funcA (program.c:6)
> ==3146==    by 0x4005C7: funcB (program.c:17)
> ==3146==    by 0x400601: main (program.c:27)
> ==3146== 
> ==3146== LEAK SUMMARY:
> ==3146==    definitely lost: 80 bytes in 4 blocks
> ==3146==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==3146==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==3146==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==3146==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==3146== 
> ==3146== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
> ==3146== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
> ```

Remember, every time when you `malloc` `free` it.

Answer (score 1):

No, each iteration not will "overwrite" data in arr, there are need to free memory at each iteration

Comment: Unless `funcA` does something fishy, each iteration will not *overwrite* data in the previously allocated array pointed to by `arr`, but the memory will become unreachable (aka lost) because the previous value of `arr` was overwritten.